# SonarQube OAuth Gitlab Redirection Glitch

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube

I run into a strange glitch with SonarQube (9.1.0.47736 Developer Edition) + GitLab ( 14.4.2-ee) Authentication.

Both services are running on self-hosted servers and have self-sigend certificates.
On the server which runs Gitlab (user facing) there is an nginx reverse-proxy to have an HTTPS end-point to the useres. (Base URL in SonarQ setting is set accordingly.)

The glitch is that when a user authenticates with his/her Gitlab credentials, he gets redirected onto the Gitlab landing page, and not on SonarQube.
In Gitlab the Callback URL is set to `https://IP:PORT/oauth2/callback/gitlab` as described in the docs.

If one then manually re-visits the SonarQube address, the user *is logged in*, so the authentication actually worked.

Before landing on the Gitlab page, there is a blink of such page:
[image: redirect-glitch]

And in the SonarQube web.logs there is this warning:

```
WARN  web[AX0pVQ771Ww8x0fzAAGu][o.s.s.a.AuthenticationError] Fail to callback authentication with 'gitlab'
com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth2AccessTokenErrorResponse: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."}
    at com.github.scribejava.core.extractors.OAuth2AccessTokenJsonExtractor.generateError(OAuth2AccessTokenJsonExtractor.java:72)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.extractors.OAuth2AccessTokenJsonExtractor.extract(OAuth2AccessTokenJsonExtractor.java:40)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.extractors.OAuth2AccessTokenJsonExtractor.extract(OAuth2AccessTokenJsonExtractor.java:18)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service.sendAccessTokenRequestSync(OAuth20Service.java:53)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service.getAccessToken(OAuth20Service.java:97)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service.getAccessToken(OAuth20Service.java:92)
    at org.sonar.auth.gitlab.GitLabIdentityProvider.onCallback(GitLabIdentityProvider.java:115)
    at org.sonar.auth.gitlab.GitLabIdentityProvider.callback(GitLabIdentityProvider.java:102)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter.handleOAuth2Provider(OAuth2CallbackFilter.java:92)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter.handleProvider(OAuth2CallbackFilter.java:75)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter.doFilter(OAuth2CallbackFilter.java:68)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:139)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.DefaultAdminCredentialsVerifierFilter.doFilter(DefaultAdminCredentialsVerifierFilter.java:89)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:139)
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.PluginsRiskConsentFilter.doFilter(PluginsRiskConsentFilter.java:77)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:139)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:108)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:81)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:68)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

The self-signed certificates of the GitLab service is imported in SQ's truststore, as the Authentication and repository access is working without problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: `does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request` sounds like it describes the behavior and the warning you're seeing. Sounds like a misconfiguration of the redirect URI.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I followed the docs: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/gitlab-integration/: "Redirect URI – enter your SonarQube URL with the path /oauth2/callback/gitlab. For example, https://sonarqube.mycompany.com/oauth2/callback/gitlab."
So in my case https://IP:port/oauth2/callback/gitlab ...